# Form with UserControl opens in VS2013 but not in VS2015

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows Form application that was originally created in VS2010.  I have since migrated it to VS2013 and VS2015.  The Application compiles fine and runs in VS2015, but if I try to open a particular form, the designer crashes giving the following error:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

It doesn't give the line of code that caused the error, but it does give a call stack as follows:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Utilities.Exceptions.ThrowEFail()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.LookupTypeSymbol()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.GetUrtTypeFromVsType(CodeTypeRef vsType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnTypePopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.CodeTypeDeclarationPopulator.OnPopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that I use custom controls on the form.  The code for the custom controls is as follows:

```
Public Class ctlServiceItem
Implements IComponent

Private _SelectedItem As AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.NA
Public Event SelectedItemChanged As EventHandler
Public Property SelectedItem As AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum
    Get
        Return _SelectedItem
    End Get
    Set(value As AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum)
        _SelectedItem = value
        Select Case SelectedItem
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.NA
                rbNA.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.OK
                rbOK.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Replaced
                rbReplaced.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Required
                rbRequired.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Suggested
                rbSuggested.Checked = True
        End Select
        RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property HeaderText As String
    Get
        Return GroupBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        GroupBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Added As Boolean
Public Property Added As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Added
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _Added = value
        If _Added Then
            rbReplaced.Text = "Added"
        Else
            rbReplaced.Text = "Replaced"
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub rbOK_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbOK.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.OK
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbSuggested_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSuggested.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Suggested
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbRequired_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbRequired.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Required
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbReplaced_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbReplaced.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Replaced
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbNA_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbNA.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.NA
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

End Class
```

The other control is

```
Public Class ctlServiceTireItem
Implements IComponent

Private _SelectedItem As AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.NA
Public Event SelectedItemChanged As EventHandler
Public Property SelectedItem As AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum
    Get
        Return _SelectedItem
    End Get
    Set(value As AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum)
        _SelectedItem = value
        Select Case SelectedItem
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.NA
                rbNA.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.OK
                rbOK.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Replaced
                rbReplaced.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Required
                rbRequired.Checked = True
            Case AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Suggested
                rbSuggested.Checked = True
        End Select
        RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property HeaderText As String
    Get
        Return GroupBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        GroupBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub rbOK_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbOK.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.OK
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbSuggested_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSuggested.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Suggested
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbRequired_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbRequired.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Required
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbReplaced_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbReplaced.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.Replaced
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub rbNA_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbNA.CheckedChanged
    _SelectedItem = AP_Data.AP_InvoiceService.SelectedItemEnum.NA
    RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

End Class
```

I can provide the designer code for the form if needed, but it is voluminous.  The controls show up in the toolbox as Project controls just like they should.  It just doesn't make sense that it will open in the designer fine in one version of VS but not the newer version.  Since it does work in an earlier version I was really hoping it is just an obscure setting or something like that.

Update:  I tried creating a brand new blank form.  I was able to drag the controls over to the new form and they showed up fine.  When I closed the form and re-opened it in the designer, I got the same error as above.  The problem is definitely with the user controls.

Comment: @LarsTech Why did you edit my subject?  The control will open fine in the designer.  Forms containing the control will not.

Comment: A lot of titles include the words "Windows Form" when they shouldn't because the Tag should cover that information.  I was trying to solve that without intending to change the information.  I edited the title again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at the bottom of
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97bfbff4-651c-47e4-8aaa-25fa2273b1b5/designer-crash-in-vs2015-in-windows-forms?forum=winformsdesigner

For some reason, I had a referenced to my own project in the project.  I think this was a trick to make projects recognize their own controls in earlier versions of Visual Studio.  Looks like this was fixed in VS 2015.  Once the project didn't have a reference to itself, the Forms with the User Controls showed up fine.